# SQL ORACLE - Join between tables not normalized

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have access to my corporate Oracle database, I am granted SELECT TABLE right **only**.

I have 2 tables containing the following data.
The only fields that link the 2 tables are DEPT_ID AND SECTOR_ID.
as you can see below  with the result expected:

[image]

If I type the following select statement,  I get duplicates of course.

```
select t1.dir_id,
       t1.dept_id,
       t1.sector_id,
       t2.place_id,
       t2.amount
from test1 t1 , 
test2 t2
where t1.dept_id = t2.dept_id
and t1.sector_id = t2.sector_id;
```

### Thanks in advance if you can help (below, tables and content for the example)

```
CREATE TABLE Test1 (
  DIR_ID INT,
  DEPT_ID INT,
  SECTOR_ID INT,
  OTHER INT);
  
CREATE TABLE Test2 (
  DEPT_ID INT,
  SECTOR_ID INT,
  PLACE_ID INT,
  AMOUNT INT);
  
INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES (1,1,1,1);
INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES (1,1,1,2);
INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES (1,1,1,3);
INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES (1,2,1,1);

INSERT INTO Test2 VALUES (1,1,1,10);
INSERT INTO Test2 VALUES (1,1,1,10);
INSERT INTO Test2 VALUES (1,1,1,20);
INSERT INTO Test2 VALUES (1,2,1,10);
```

Fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5a658/1/0

Comment: You have three duplicated rows (1,1,1,10) in Test2 and that is causes the duplication in the joined query. Do you really need to store this duplicated rows? Also, try to avoid using old-style joins [Bad Habits to Kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Unfortunately,  I cannot change the content of the tables.

Comment: In table2 the duplicates are normal as it is an amount received at different moment (other columns are not displayed here),  As you can see in the picture the only additional field in the result is DIR_ID  which I can only get by joining with DEPT_ID and SECTOR_ID and this create duplicated rows as a result.  I just need to be able to fetch  DIR_ID  from a pair of DEPT_ID, SECTOR_ID in the second table where DIR_ID does not exists .

Comment: Please look at the image and the result expected.  I need to know which is the DIR_ID for the rows in table 2.   for 1 couple (DEPT_ID, SECTOR_ID)  I want 1 DIR_ID .  The problem is that table 1 contains multiple duplicates  (DIR_ID, DEPT_ID, SECTOR_ID).

Comment: "...The only fields that link the 2 tables are DEPT_ID AND SECTOR_ID..." -- that's not strictly true. Those columns relate many rows to many rows, so there's no clear linking between tables. In short the expected result does not make sense according to the details in the question. More information is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You may join the test2 table with the `distinct dir_id,dept_id,sector_id from test1` as the following:

```
select t1.dir_id,
       t1.dept_id,
       t1.sector_id,
       t2.place_id,
       t2.amount
from (select distinct dir_id,dept_id,sector_id from test1) t1 
join 
test2 t2
on t1.dept_id = t2.dept_id
and t1.sector_id = t2.sector_id;
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/T-LfYW-4).

Answer (score 0):

In general, the join condition in every join should fully include the primary key columns of at least one of the tables.  Your example does not do that, which is why there are problems.

To construct a join relation between two tables, A and B, take every row in A and match each one with every row in B.  This intermediate result is called a Cartesian product.  If table A has 50 rows and table B has 1,000 rows, this Cartesian product will have 50 x 1,000 or 50,000 rows.

The result of the join will be every match in the Cartesian product of A and B that meets the join condition.

In your test data, table `TEST1` has 3 rows that have (`DEPT_ID`,`SECTOR_ID`) = (1,1).  Table `TEST2` likewise has 3 such rows.  So, your result will include 9 (3x3) rows that have (`DEPT_ID`,`SECTOR_ID`) = (1,1).

That is all anyone can say about this without more information from you.  You seem to only one 3 rows in the result for (1,1) but you don't say how you want to do this.

You could, for example, use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to arbitrarily number the rows in `TEST1` and `TEST2` and join the 1st numbered row in `TEST1` to the 1st numbered row in `TEST2`.  But you need to give the requirements.